# Swift SpriteKit give to a missile touch direction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, trigonometry

I have a spaceship (top-down view) that needs to fire missiles in all directions. What i want is that missile goes to the right direction (set by user touch on the screen).
Here is what i tried:

```
    let angle = atan2((ship?.position.y)! - touchLocation.y, (ship?.position.x)! - touchLocation.x)
                var dx:CGFloat = CGFloat(cosf(Float(angle)))
                var dy:CGFloat = CGFloat(sinf(Float(angle)))
                missile.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy))
```

With this code missile goes above to the north of the screen, but i need that he can go to all degrees directions set by user touches location. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Try swapping the ship and touch positions in the `atan2` function.

Comment: i tried your suggestion...but unfortunately, the missile takes strange way ... I just want to go straight in the direction of the position touched on the screen ... any other suggestions?